# Linux on Dell Inspiron 3000 2 in 1?

Tags: gnome, laptop, touch-screen

I did some looking around but I couldn't find much. I'm trying to figure out which distributions work best with a [Dell Inspiron 3000](http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/inspiron-11-3000-2-in-1/spd/inspiron-11-3168-2-in-1-laptop/fncwd1201b). It's a 2-in-1, so I'd prefer touchscreen use too but auto-rotating isn't really necessary as long as flipping the back down turns off the keyboard and touchpad

Anyone already installed a dist on one of these? I'm thinking mainly Gnome

Comment: it ships with Ubuntu 14.04 here in India. you can try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know GNOME (which is a Desktop Environment, not a Linux distro) supports touchscreen and screen rotation.  So you can install Debian, CentOS, or Ubuntu, with GNOME KDE and you should be fine.